# Web page stretches in width when data is entered without new line character

Tags: html, html-table

I have a webpage with tabular structure with width of table 800px.

I am fetching some data from DB and displaying it on page,
but when the length of the content goes behind  this 800px the page gets stretched beyond 800px.

According to me the width should noy increase from 800px and the extra characters should go to next line.

Please have a look on these two pages to understand the exact situation:

[Link 1](http://www.articlesnmore.in/ShowArticle-articleid-16-title-why_to_use_this.htm)

[Link 2](http://www.articlesnmore.in/ShowArticle-articleid-7-title-Online_Pharmacies_and_its_benifits.htm)

Answer (score 0):

The page uses the `pre` element, which means preformatted text, i.e. line breaks shall appear in the display exactly as in the source and no new line breaks shall be added by the browser. The fix depends on how you wish the content to appear.

Normally you should use e.g. `div` element instead and add markup that creates forced line breaks or empty lines as needed, e.g. simply (and simplistically) `<br>` for forced break.

Comment: pre tag is a necessity for me because i need to use display some tags as content , for which i have used pre and code tags. can u give me example such that understand it.

Comment: Using `pre` (or `code`) does not make markup shown as content; you would still need to use `&lt;` for `<`. (Using `xmp` would be a different matter, but it is regarded as very obsolete, though it works well.)
From the content, it looks like the best option is to generate `div` instead of `pre` and to wrap text that is now a single line (but paragraph-long) in the `pre` into a `p` element, a paragraph. Possibly some of them should really be heading elements.